# How do I convert an HTML Entity Number into a character using plain JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-encode

I'm looking for a way to convert HTML entity numbers into a character using plain JavaScript or jQuery.

For example, I have a string that looks like this (Thank you, jQuery! Punk.)

```
Range1&#45;of-5
```

And what I need is:

```
Range1-of-5
```

I've found String.fromCharCode() where I can get the character with just the decimal value, but I'd like to see if anyone else has a solution before I possibly reinvent the wheel. :)

Comment: That’s not an entity but a [normal character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.3.1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("<div/>").html("Range1&#45;of-5").text()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/durilai/tkwEh/

Comment: This looks to be the simplest and most robust. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The jQuery way looks nicer, but here's a pure JS version if you're interested:

```
function decode(encodedString) {
    var tmpElement = document.createElement('span');
    tmpElement.innerHTML = encodedString;
    return tmpElement.innerHTML;
}

decode("Range1&#45;of-5");
```

Comment: Cool. Worked for me :)

Answer (score 5):

No need to use jQuery for this simple task:

```
'Range1&#45;of-5'.replace(/&#(\d+);/g, function(match, number){ return String.fromCharCode(number); })
```

The same principle can be applied to &#xHHHH; and &name; entities.

Comment: This worked but as I explore corner cases I'm concerned it's not going to scale well into different use cases. I did upvote it as it strikes me as very useful, just not as robust as I think I might need going above and beyond the initial use case above.